# Orchard Workflow Event

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I'am handling a custom workflow event :

```
_workflowManager.TriggerEvent("ProductAdded", null, () =>
    new Dictionary<string, object> {{"ProductName", model.Name}});
```

Now on my dashboard I'm trying to access the Name in a simple `Notify Activity`
*Product {ProductName} has been added successfuly !*

for some reason i'm always getting Product has been added successfuly !

am i missing something ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Cross post from: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/7999

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

`{Workflow.State:ProductName}`

Comment: in the notify Activity `GetState<string>("Message")` Its aways getting "has been added" without the {Workflow.State:ProductName} does this mean the parameters are not  well formated ? but in the activitycontext in Notify => Tokens my tokens are passed to the activity